# Undefined is not an object(evaluating 'WebRTCModule.mediaStreamTrackGetSources')

Tags: react-native, webrtc

I am developing with react-native webrtc app. When get local stream, have a bug as below:

> Undefined is not an object(evaluating
>   'WebRTCModule.mediaStreamTrackGetSources')

This `MediaStreamTrack` object is an object of `react-native-webrtc` lib. Can someone suggest me? Thanks in advance!

Image:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/gSeQR.png

Comment: Can you add some code? are you sure you're requiring `WebRTCModule`?

Comment: This is the line code: >`MediaStreamTrack.getSources(sourceInfos => {}`

Comment: MediaStreamTrack is imported from `react-native-webrtc` lib

Answer (score 3):

I got a similar error on iOS. I found I had failed to link `libRCTWebRTC.a`. Covered in more detail in step #4 here: https://github.com/react-native-webrtc/react-native-webrtc/blob/master/Documentation/iOSInstallation.md#step-4-linkinclude-necessary-libraries

For Android, the process is covered here: https://github.com/react-native-webrtc/react-native-webrtc/blob/master/Documentation/AndroidInstallation.md

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer by adding `WebRTCModule` from `react-native-webrtc` lib to all settings and .java file as settings.gradle, build.gradle, manifest file and MainApplication.java.